# WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount "Field does not exist"

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am trying to extend the Simple Membership to include FirstName, SecondName and Email address, however I am getting some problems with the CreateUserAndAccount.

So basically in the RegisterModel I have added the following :-

```
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Text is required")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Second Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Text is required")]
    public string SecondName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\w+([-+.]*[\w-]+)*@(\w+([-.]?\w+)){1,}\.\w{2,4}$")]
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
```

in the Register.cshtml I have added the user inputs :-

```
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SecondName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SecondName)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ContactEmail)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactEmail)
        </li>
```

and then in the AccountController.cs I have the following :-

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                var UserInfo =
                new
                {
                    FirstName = model.FirstName,
                    SecondName = model.SecondName,
                    ContactEmail = model.ContactEmail
                };

                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, UserInfo);
                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

The problem is that when it tries to do the

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, UserInfo);
```

I am getting an error with the following :-

Invalid column name 'FirstName'.

Invalid column name 'SecondName'.

Invalid column name 'ContactEmail'.

Is it because the User table is not being created with the fields?  If it is, how can I create those fields.  I already have the initialize set

```
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks

*******UPDATE****************************************

This is the UserProfile

```
    public class UserProfile : ProfileBase
{
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public virtual string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.GetPropertyValue("FirstName").ToString());
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetPropertyValue("FirstName", value);
        }
    }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public virtual string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.GetPropertyValue("LastName").ToString());
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetPropertyValue("LastName", value);
        }
    }

    [Display(Name = "Contact Email")]
    public virtual string ContactEmail
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.GetPropertyValue("ContactEmail").ToString());
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetPropertyValue("ContactEmail", value);
        }
    }

    public static UserProfile GetProfile(string username)
    {
        return Create(username) as UserProfile;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add these three new fields (FirstName, SecondName and ContactEmail) to your UserProfile class which inherits DbContext.

UserProfile class is defined in your accounts model.

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
}
```

Make sure to delete your tables so that previous tables are deleted.

Comment: I have already added them in the UserProfile!  Please see updated question

Comment: After further investigation, I have decided to go with 2 different tables, and keep the Membership tables intact.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you used simple membership befor you perform those change to your model. It caused that SimpleMembership created the `UserProfile` table with the default columns (id and name).

In this situation, setting `autoCreateTables: true` doesn't help because your tables exist! but they don't have new columns.

So you need to remove those 4 tables and let the db initializer to create new valid tables for you.